# How can I write this pattern synonym without ambiguous type errors?

Tags: haskell, pattern-synonyms

Using `ViewPatterns` and `Data.Typeable`, I’ve managed to write a function that allows me to write something resembling case analysis on types. Observe:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, PatternSynonyms, RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables
           , TypeApplications, TypeOperators, ViewPatterns #-}

import Data.Typeable

viewEqT :: forall b a. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe ((a :~: b), b)
viewEqT x = case eqT @a @b of
  Just Refl -> Just (Refl, x)
  Nothing -> Nothing

evilId :: Typeable a => a -> a
evilId (viewEqT @Int -> Just (Refl, n)) = n + 1
evilId (viewEqT @String -> Just (Refl, str)) = reverse str
evilId x = x
```

The above `evilId` function is very evil, indeed, since it uses `Typeable` to completely subvert parametricity:

```
ghci> evilId True
True
ghci> evilId "hello"
"olleh"
```

Since I love being evil, I am very pleased with this, but the above syntax is very noisy. I would love to be able to write the same code more clearly, so I decided to write a pattern synonym:

```
pattern EqT :: forall b a. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a ~ b) => b -> a
pattern EqT x <- (viewEqT @b -> Just (Refl, x))
```

I figured that I would be able to use this pattern synonym to make my evil case analysis much easier to read:

```
evilId :: Typeable a => a -> a
evilId (EqT (n :: Int)) = n + 1
evilId (EqT (str :: String)) = reverse str
evilId x = x
```

Sadly, this does not work at all. GHC does not seem to consult my type annotations before typechecking the pattern, so it believes `b` is an ambiguous variable in each pattern. Is there any way I can cleanly wrap these patterns with a pattern synonym, or will I be stuck with my longer view patterns?

Comment: Does it work if you change `viewEqT` to use `Proxy`?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I couldn’t figure out a way to get a pattern synonym to take an expression as an “argument” to be used in a view pattern instead of taking patterns, so `Proxy` didn’t seem to help.

Comment: It seems that pattern synonyms only allow information to get "out" of them. I.e. we can't define `f (Plus1 5) = ...` where `Plus1 n = ((== n+1) -> True)`. Here `n` must be an "out" pattern, not an input value. IIRC in Scala and extractor objects this is possible (albeit in Haskell we have view patterns which can do the same with a more verbose syntax). It would also be nice to type-apply in patterns like `EqT @ Int n` but `@` in patterns already means something else, and again this would be an "in" type argument.

Comment: I’ve opened GHC tickets [#13158](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13158) and [#13159](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13159) related to this issue, the former related to this program not typechecking and the latter related to @chi’s request for visible type application in patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to find some clean syntax to implement your `evilId` function, you can write it like this:

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables, GADTs, TypeApplications #-}

module Demo where

import Data.Typeable

evilId :: forall a. Typeable a => a -> a
evilId x
  | Just Refl <- eqT @a @Int    = x+1
  | Just Refl <- eqT @a @String = reverse x
  | otherwise                   = x
```

This doesn't help with the ambiguities surrounding your pattern synonyms, unfortunately.