# using type classes to provide alternative implementations for when using Acid-State

Tags: haskell, testing, typeclass, monad-transformers, acid-state

I wrote a web application using scotty and acid state, now i would like to use type classes to be able to provide alternative implementations for the capabilities of my application for testing.
I get the general idea of it and am able to apply it so simple examples but since im am using acid state there are a lot of type classes and template haskell involved which i am not entirely comfortable with yet.

so i have these straight-forward classes for the different capabilities

```
class Logging m where
  log :: T.Text -> m ()

class Server m where
  body :: m B.ByteString
  respond :: T.Text -> m ()
  setHeader :: T.Text -> T.Text -> m ()

class Db m where
  dbQuery :: (MethodState event ~ Database,QueryEvent event) => event -> m (EventResult event)
  dbUpdate :: (MethodState event ~ Database,UpdateEvent event) => event -> m (EventResult event)
```

and i also provided instances for them for my "production" monad.

But when it comes to the database capability i cant get to work what i want.

the class looks like this

```
class Db m where
  dbQuery :: (MethodState event ~ Database,QueryEvent event) => event -> m (EventResult event)
  dbUpdate :: (MethodState event ~ Database,UpdateEvent event) => event -> m (EventResult event)
```

and the instance for the production monad works fine since it only passes the event to the update and query functions of acid state, but for a test monad i would like to have something like this:
    instance Db Test where
      dbQuery (GetVersion) = use (testDb . clientVersion)
      dbQuery (GetUser name) = preuse (testDb . users . ix name)
      dbUpdate (PutUser name user) = users %= M.insert name user
      ...
so that I can match on GetVersion,GetUser etc. (which are generated by the template haskell function makeAcidic ... ) and specify how they should be handled in the test environment.

But I get the error:

```
Could not deduce: event ~ GetVersion
from the context: (MethodState event ~ Database, QueryEvent event)
  bound by the type signature for:
              dbQuery :: (MethodState event ~ Database, QueryEvent event) =>
                        event -> Test (EventResult event)
  at Main.hs:88:3-9
‘event’ is a rigid type variable bound by
  the type signature for:
    dbQuery :: forall event.
                (MethodState event ~ Database, QueryEvent event) =>
                event -> Test (EventResult event)
  at Main.hs:88:3
• In the pattern: GetVersion
In an equation for ‘dbQuery’:
    dbQuery (GetVersion) = use (testDb . clientVersion)
In the instance declaration for ‘Db Test’
• Relevant bindings include
  dbQuery :: event -> Test (EventResult event)
    (bound at Main.hs:88:3)
```

i guess thats because GetVersion, GetUser etc. all have a their different own types. So is there a way to do this?

---

### Incorporating suggestions

I tried the suggestions proposed by Peter Amidon but sadly it still doesnt compile here is my test code

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}               -- For type equality
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}       -- For type equality
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}        -- For EventResult
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-} -- For writing castWithWitness
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}    -- For convenience
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Lens
import Data.Acid
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T
import Types
import Data.Typeable

main = return ()

getUser :: Username -> Query Database (Maybe User)
getUser name = preview (users . ix name)

getVersion :: Query Database T.Text
getVersion = view clientVersion

$(makeAcidic ''Database ['getUser,'getVersion])

castWithWitness :: forall b a. (Typeable a, Typeable b)
                => a -> Maybe (b :~: a, b)
castWithWitness x = case eqT @a @b of
                      Nothing -> Nothing
                      Just Refl -> Just (Refl, x)

exampleFunction :: forall a. QueryEvent a => a -> EventResult a
exampleFunction (castWithWitness @GetVersion -> (Just Refl, Just GetVersion)) = "1.0"
exampleFunction (castWithWitness @GetUser -> (Just Refl, Just (GetUser n))) = Nothing
```

and here the error

```
Main.hs:124:49: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe
                                      (GetVersion :~: a, GetVersion)’
                  with actual type ‘(Maybe (t1 :~: t2), t0)’
    • In the pattern: (Just Refl, Just GetVersion)
      In the pattern:
        castWithWitness @GetVersion -> (Just Refl, Just GetVersion)
      In an equation for ‘exampleFunction’:
          exampleFunction
            (castWithWitness @GetVersion -> (Just Refl, Just GetVersion))
            = "1.0"
    • Relevant bindings include
        exampleFunction :: a -> EventResult a (bound at Main.hs:124:1)

Main.hs:124:61: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘t0’
                  with actual type ‘Maybe GetVersion’
        ‘t0’ is untouchable
          inside the constraints: t2 ~ t1
          bound by a pattern with constructor:
                    Refl :: forall k (a :: k). a :~: a,
                  in an equation for ‘exampleFunction’
          at Main.hs:124:55-58
    • In the pattern: Just GetVersion
      In the pattern: (Just Refl, Just GetVersion)
      In the pattern:
        castWithWitness @GetVersion -> (Just Refl, Just GetVersion)

Main.hs:125:46: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe (GetUser :~: a, GetUser)’
                  with actual type ‘(Maybe (t4 :~: t5), t3)’
    • In the pattern: (Just Refl, Just (GetUser n))
      In the pattern:
        castWithWitness @GetUser -> (Just Refl, Just (GetUser n))
      In an equation for ‘exampleFunction’:
          exampleFunction
            (castWithWitness @GetUser -> (Just Refl, Just (GetUser n)))
            = Nothing
    • Relevant bindings include
        exampleFunction :: a -> EventResult a (bound at Main.hs:124:1)

Main.hs:125:79: error:
    • Could not deduce: MethodResult a ~ Maybe a0
      from the context: t5 ~ t4
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                  Refl :: forall k (a :: k). a :~: a,
                in an equation for ‘exampleFunction’
        at Main.hs:125:52-55
      Expected type: EventResult a
        Actual type: Maybe a0
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the expression: Nothing
      In an equation for ‘exampleFunction’:
          exampleFunction
            (castWithWitness @GetUser -> (Just Refl, Just (GetUser n)))
            = Nothing
    • Relevant bindings include
        exampleFunction :: a -> EventResult a (bound at Main.hs:124:1)
```

Comment: Can you make `event` a parameter of `Db`?  `class Db event m`

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Wouldnt I need to pass in a specific type at some point? I dont want to do that since i want to be able to use all the different acid state events from within my monad

Comment: Yes you would need to. If you can't change the classes, the only way to do anything with a given `event` is to use the `QueryEvent`/`UpdateEvent` classes, but the post doesn't say what they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, what you want should be possible, because a `QueryEvent` or `UpdateEvent` is a `Method`, and a `Method` is `Typeable`. `Typeable` lets us use functions from `Data.Typeable` to inspect what specific type we have at runtime, which we can't really normally do.

Here's a small, self-contained example that doesn't directly use `acid-state` but begins to illustrate the idea:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
```

These aren't strictly necessary, but make it possible to make nicer syntax for matching on `Event`s.

```
import Data.Typeable
```

We need functions from this module to access the run-time typing information.

```
data GetVersion = GetVersion
data GetUser = GetUser String
class Typeable a => QueryEvent a where
instance QueryEvent GetVersion where
instance QueryEvent GetUser where
```

A simplified set of types/classes to emulate what `acid-state` should produce.

```
pattern IsEvent p <- (cast -> Just p)
```

This "pattern synonym" makes it so that we can write `IsEvent p` on the LHS of a pattern match and have it work the same way as if we had written `(cast -> Just p)`. This latter is a "view pattern" which essentially runs the function `cast` on the input and then pattern matches it against `Just p`. `cast` is a function defined in `Data.Typeable`: `cast :: forall a b. (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b`.  This means that if we write, for example, `(cast -> Just GetVersion)`, what happens is that `cast` tries to convert the argument into a value of type `GetVersion`, which is then pattern-matched against the value-level `GetVersion` symbol; if the conversion fails (implying that the event is something else), `cast` returns `Nothing`, so this pattern doesn't match.  This lets us write:

```
exampleFunction :: QueryEvent a => a -> String
exampleFunction (IsEvent GetVersion) = "get version"
exampleFunction (IsEvent (GetUser a)) = "get user " ++ a
```

This then works:

```
λ> exampleFunction GetVersion
"get version"
λ> exampleFunction (GetUser "foo")
"get user foo"
```

---

Your situation is a bit more complicated, since the (type of) the RHS of the function depends on the type of the input.  We will need some more extensions for this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}               -- For type equality
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}       -- For type equality
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}        -- For EventResult
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-} -- For writing castWithWitness
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}    -- For convenience
```

We can also add `EventResult` to our dummy simple `QueryEvent`:

```
class Typeable a => QueryEvent a where
  type EventResult a
instance QueryEvent GetVersion where
  type EventResult GetVersion = Int
instance QueryEvent GetUser where
  type EventResult GetUser = String
```

Instead of using `cast`, we can use

```
castWithWitness :: forall b a. (Typeable a, Typeable b)
                => a -> Maybe (b :~: a, b)
castWithWitness x = case eqT @a @b of
                      Nothing -> Nothing
                      Just Refl -> Just (Refl, x)
```

The `@a` and `@b` are using `TypeApplications` to apply `eqT` to the types that `castWithWitness` was applied to, which are bound via `ScopedTypeVariables` using the `forall` in the type signature. `castWithWitness` is like `cast`, but in addition to the "casted" variable, it returns a proof that the passed-in types are the same.  Unfortunately, this makes it a bit harder to use: the `IsEvent` pattern synonym can't be used, and the relevant type needs to be passed in directly:

```
exampleFunction :: forall a. QueryEvent a => a -> EventResult a
exampleFunction (castWithWitness @GetVersion -> Just (Refl, GetVersion)) = 1
exampleFunction (castWithWitness @GetUser -> Just (Refl, GetUser n)) = n
```

This works, because in each case, after matching on `Refl`, GHC knows on the RHS of the function what `a` is and can reduce the `EventResult` type family.

Comment: Thanks this looks very promising but i cant get it to work for my instance Db Test
for this line in the instance declaration
`dbQuery (IsEvent (GetUser name)) = return Nothing`
i get this error:
`Could not deduce: MethodResult event ~ Maybe a0
      from the context: (MethodState event ~ Database, QueryEvent event)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   dbQuery :: (MethodState event ~ Database, QueryEvent event) =>
                              event -> Test lg (EventResult event)`

Comment: Aha, that roughly makes sense. I will add a section showing something that might fix it by bringing a type equality into scope (at the cost of some nice syntax).

Comment: @HaroldFincher Sorry I missed the type family in the result type earlier! The new section in the solution should work better.

Comment: thanks for all your help but i still cant get it to work. I added an extra sections to my questions.

Comment: @HaroldFincher - My mistake, can you try the edit I just made to `exampleFunction`?

Comment: yes thank you very much! And there is no option to provide cleaner syntax? using a pattern synonym or something?

Comment: I agree that it feels like there should be, but I don't know of anything particularly great. A little bit of experimenting with various patterns failed to find anything that didn't result in ambiguous type variable errors. I have "digging through GHC's implementation inference in pattern synonyms" on my todo list, but haven't gotten around to it yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41753345/how-can-i-write-this-pattern-synonym-without-ambiguous-type-errors gives a slightly nicer syntax, however.